# How is this popup message created / programmed?

Tags: qt-creator, qt5.4, qtwidgets

I recently noticed the following popup message ("6 occurrences replaced") in Qt Creator (3.4.2).

I like its style and want to use it in my own application. But how is it done? Is this a particular widget or what else? Can someone point me in the right direction.

[image: popup]

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own window with round corners like that with text in the middle paid show it when you want too make the window so it takes a parameter text and you can add different text each time and show

Comment: yes I could, but I was wondering if Qt came up with some new widget for that.